# jquery parameters synchronisation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have written a shopping basket using js, and i am updating the total sum of the basket automatically when one selects a quantity. my problem is that, when i drop a product, the total value of the sum does not update but on page refresh.

here is the code:

```
  $('#add-to-basket select').selectbox();
    $('#contents select').selectbox().change(function (e) {
        var product = $(this).parents('.product');
        var ppu     = product.find('.ppu').val();
        product.find('.price .wrapper .value').text($(this).val() * ppu);

        var total   = 0;

        $('.product .price .value').each(function (index, value) {
            total += +$(value).text();
        });

        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        form.ajaxSubmit(function () {
        });

        $('#total .value').text(total);
                    $('#my_basket .basket_value').text(total);
    });

    $('#delivery #address a').qtip({
        content: 'Vei putea reveni la coș dând click pe <span>Coșul Meu</span> în meniu.'
    });

    $('.drop-item').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parents(form);
        var item = $(this).parents('li');
        var total   = 0;



        $('.product .price .value').each(function (index, value) {
            total +=  +$(value).text();
        });

        $('#total .value').text(total);

        item.remove();
        form.ajaxSubmit(function() {});

        if ($('#contents li').length < 1)
        {
            $('#basket').remove();
            $('#basket-breadcrumbs').remove();

            $('#main').append('<p class="message">Coșul tău este gol.</p>');
        }
    });
```

my problem is at the removing item feature. how can i make the total value update on item remove?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you probably just need to move your `item.remove()` call up a few lines inside of your .drop-item click handler.  You need to make sure you remove the item from the DOM before you retrieve the new list of inputs that you're going to total up.

Comment: also, i get NaN some times when i include non integer values (e.g 17.4, etc) any idea how can i get rid of this?   thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help.  As for your values: $().text returns a string which can be implicitly converted to an integer when you use +=, but float values don't do the same.  You'll want to use parseFloat to evaluate the data before you add it to your total.